# transformar wav em byte[]

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Preciso juntar três áudios. Pensei e optei por transforma-los em um cadeia de bytes para em seguida, concatena-los. No entanto está dando erro no

`File.ReadAllBytes :  " "ControllerBase.File(byte[],string)" é um método, que não é válido no contexto fornecido"`

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> recebertexto([FromForm]Texto txt)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                string conteudo = string.Format("Texto: {0}", txt.texto);

                await GerarAudioAsync("01a2d0519c21413686eddcdfed3d3a3d", txt.texto);



                byte[] arquivo1 = File.ReadAllBytes(GetVideoAsByte(@"1.wav"));
                byte[] arquivo2 = File.ReadAllBytes(GetVideoAsByte(@"2.wav"));
                byte[] arquivo3 = File.ReadAllBytes(GetVideoAsByte(@"3.wav"));

                byte[] arquivo4 = new byte[arquivo1.Length + arquivo2.Length + arquivo3.Length];

                long i;
                long j;

                for (i = 0; i < arquivo1.Length; i++)
                    arquivo4[i] = arquivo1[i];

                for (j = 0; j < arquivo2.Length; j++, i++)
                    arquivo4[i] = arquivo2[j];

                File.WriteAllBytes("final.mp3", arquivo4);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { 
            ViewBag.Error = "Erro ao gerar o  arquivo!";
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Método para transformar em byte:

```
  public static byte[] GetVideoAsByte(string videoPath)
        {
            byte[] byteData = null;

            using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient())
            {
                var url = new Uri(videoPath);
                byteData = client.DownloadData(url);
            }
            return byteData;
        }
```

Comment: Para que tentar chamar `File.ReadAllBytes` se o seu próprio código já te entrega a array de bytes?

Comment: Cara você está tentando juntar arquivos .wav em um .mp3 assim na raça? Não acho que vai dar certo isso não, esses arquivos possuem cabeçalhos, não são arquivos .raw.